# What is the functional difference between 4049 and 4069 hex inverters? (The 40106 IC's too)

Tags: timer, switching

For simple R/C oscillator circuits driving LED's - I would like to run 6 independent frequencies with one 4069 IC for random flashing "super computer" display with around 450 LED's in total.

The 4069 does a good job with two gates. I couldn't get it to work with one though.

Comment: Isn't some kind of addressable LED array + a micro controller a better fit for your need?

Answer (score 6):

Best to hit the datasheets for specific differences.  There are several.

1. 4049 has 16 pins and significantly-different pinout.  4049 has much higher drive capability compared to regular CMOS.
2. 4069 is a bog-standard hex inverter.  There are several similar devices in the CMOS family, all with the same pinout.
3. 40106 is similar to 4069 but with Schmitt-Trigger.  You can build 6 oscillators using one gate each in a 40106.

Comment: For number 3, no you can't. Any useful oscillator will need to connect to another inverter on the chip as a drive inverter.  So, I've seen most articles on the subject had similar experience to mine - three useful oscillators can be built with a hex inverter.

Answer (score 3):

The cd4069 is the glitch free version of the original cd4049 (and the Vdd pin was moved to the more common location vs the atypical location of cd4049).

A cd40106 is a Schmitt trigger input and a much better choice for an oscillator.

Answer (score 3):

Most CMOS circuits allow inputs in the range of Vss to Vdd,
with a threshold in the middle 1/3 of that range.

CD4069 is an inverter logic part with standard
CMOS input behavior.

CD4049 allows inputs from Vss to 20.5V; the input
is  not clamped to Vdd, only to the negative rail with a Zener.  It also has higher output current than most CMOS gates.

CD40106 has two thresholds, a low one for high-to-low
transitions, and a higher one for low-to-high  input swing.
That's called hysteresis, and it adds phase shift and
confers power efficiency in oscillator or low-slew-rate input applications.

Answer (score 2):

For single inverter oscillators choose ones with input hysteresis. The 40106 is one such.

A 74C14 also, with a higher hysteresis range than the 40106.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. I will order the 40106. For my current project, I'm using a 2 gate option and 8 of the 4069's. The random speed of the independent circuits is part of the design.

Answer (score 2):

```
                                   Schmitt  Schmitt
               Hex Inv   Hex Inv   Hex Inv  Hex Inv 
               4049UB    4069UB    40106B   74AC14 
               ------    ------    ------   -------
   Rout(nom.)  62.5 Ω     400 Ω     400 Ω    15   Ω    25'C Vdd=5V 
   Rout(max.)  125  Ω     784 Ω     784 Ω    18.3 Ω    25'C Vdd=5V 
    
   Vdd range   3~18 V    3~18 V    3~18 V     2~6 V*   25'C Vdd=5V 
   tLH,tHL     120 ns    110 ns    200 ns     15ns max 25'C Vdd=5V CL=50pF
```

-* Rout for 6V logic is rated for VOL at 5V-10% or 4.5V . This became std to rate at 10% below standard voltages like 3.3-10% or max -10% to simulate worst case Vdd.

- Rout is calculated using **Rout=(Vol (nom/max) / Iout (fixed) )**
- Similar for Voh, Roh=(Vdd-Voh)/Ioh,  but is same Rol by design.

The advantage of 74AC14 for LED Astable oscillator is the LED current at 3.3V can easily drive 10 mA with a small Rs including Rout in the voltage drop.   e.g. using White=3.0V @10mA,  300mV/10mA = 30 Ohms thus Rs =  15 Ω + Rout

or 20 mA from Vf= 3.1 @ 20mA, Vdd=5V,  (5-3.1)/20 mA= 1900 mV/20 mA=95 Ω so Rs= 80 Ω + Rout  or choose Rs=100 ohms for std value.

You can use ceramic caps with Rf up to 33 MΩ and choose any T or f from the RC values. example below for 1 IC uses 204 mW peak power for 6 LEDs thus 34 mW / LED @ 10 mA times 450 LED's = 15.3 Watts. using 75 IC's

[FALSTAD SIM](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgbALCAMB00IKyIgTnRzGQEZYA4IB2VRfMaMHBVfRMERaRkCfRgUwFoccAoAOa4GqBjjE4ATDBh8c%20AMzgoo3JParmcRLlhgGC2AqU7ofAE5qNYiCobMciC7lshVOVNM24nCqADMAdwATcwB7AAcAHQBHQxxcNyNJbl4ZMFhJYmJ1CBxiBSYlLXhJOTBpD2k2XE83Bmkg0MjY%20MSEhLhoMoAlEB4GLgVpAf6arVZmQ2KZbT5JaCJ%208RlR4dYQADVg4PnF2ur2KuEN7d3LfKhIZRuHBHuzQJcrqEv62Sfrr7tZAGMb9wiey4bhHWAkfLQKTQfB0CBgIgVGDwKF8f4KaA-ST0d7MSSZB6EwkpLjsQySfSeYySYYI9REKBdVFPDEvECs3F8FmEG4KHmaZx8tkc653Ql7JYQdY1KWVBhQM7larS9iy96NELhaJxWAddrI7qC-ny9beRyCsDWdnGmTm%20RKDmqBSW3HInR4fTsowmWRCbFAkD%203BSWaCVjXVTw14hrRyRSMEOqRCI13aXSe6Y%20syWZMBxB1M1OHMFhiQZiFpXKZg1MvqkBNLWtXX6zqlCVV1jsWsrBU7Zz56TXRAh0W4Ilcxh1Iclj4JwdQYdeexoufvKOu6agwOZKQKe2Y%20hgfOMlH8f6LwNZcNQSRXqZGLf4tCWnB%20IgkRCSVBEUynicX44L1vRl-zqQC6mA2Ri0qOoALqasiHFBYlm7FNu1cXtdnEecHDQiA8SvDVmm1No9VbQ1oMvF4CMZHx%20xTSCByo20nHtVdGIYu83XTAxvRYMwhHXSChPw0M-RxSCgyyCYzDYjlIOddhIJKd09F44x%20ItJSryFZiHCLa0byvNVlLo7DWHWHAUxMwj601FodTIxIujKZCLMqazLIwrY%200sXTjg5Y4EPFblXjqXTlInQLwsxPSV3kwiJK4-EFiJNKSTJeBUEoCgiCs-MKj3A1UX%20a5IJWUycC3D0IC-Mh1EkEh9HyJYmX4T4wvnOKnjeY43kii5XGOa4gtYRCHnbPqUz67zFXMqaxAg2yGwc0j9Rc5x%20qvY5KoMqRtNeVxdrjJQyu29Q9O4j11KzMMKu2hpRNjBREOWQZ1lGBxQ3wpRVB4VxCmkCZEAAfUgEGiBB18UD5EHQbgHAQZ4KGQbgPdsT4AAPdkSH6C7yFQPGdBvKAAFcAGcAEsADsBCicmwmpgAbABPemGQAQQAYXyen6cCSmABcAAt6Z6cnYkcemAEMdg4YJ6cFsJ6emTYsZxpZSQYRR2FJJQSZAAAFABbaXMdiBYFHp42AHUABp6cN6WADc6ZienqAga2bfp-wwnMemwHpgAZABRAARcn1cQBRCYpU6rMDT0oHYAAVWB6YAZUFjhAml8xBfpr3yYAWXz%20mFlvPgwg2IHWF4Zhf06XBq9wJY67yah%20ObBxW4pQMZE7xvkWb-ga%20TAfqwb7vR9b%20FJ-rrum9tVuXoXoeZ5XoA)

[image]

### Recommendation

- Simpler designs exist using binary counters in the 74AC series.
- Using 74AC series is most efficient for power dissipation at 3V.